# change gnome evolution keyboard accels

Tags: gnome, gnome3, evolution

I tried to change some gnome evolution keyboard accelerators.
I tried to edit `~/.config/evolution/accels` which seems to hold all the defined keyboard accelerators. Unfortunately my modifications of this file are not used by evolution and instead this file gets overwritten with the defaults all the time I open evolution.

I even killed all evolution processes before edititing `~/.config/evolution/accels` but that didn't help -- evolution still doesn't respect the file's contents and overwrites it.

**Any idea how to configure keyboard accelerators for evolution?**

Answer (score 2):

I found out myself that I've to remove the comment semicolons in front of the lines in `~/.config/evolution/accels` while evolution is stopped. Then the uncommented lines are respected by evolution. Yet evolution overwrites `~/.config/evolution/accels` but it keeps the edits.

Example of `~/.config/evolution/accels` with a F8 beeing assigned

`; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/mail/mail-goto-menu" "")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/mail/mail-folder-select-thread" "<Primary>h")
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/mail/mail-to-do-bar" "F8")
; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/mail/mail-find" "<Primary><Shift>f")`