# Evolution menu bar not showing

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-18.04, evolution

At the top of my Evolution window I used to have a menu bar with items such as 'Files', 'Edit', 'View' and the like. But after experimenting a little with the different views, I have accidentally removed this menu bar.

Quite annoying, as it was my point of entry for changing the views in the first place, and no I cannot revert the change.

I feel like there should be a simple GUI way of making the menu bar show up again. But I haven't found that.

Instead I have skimmed through a bunch of config files to identify where this change of setting has been recorded. No luck.

I also tried manipulating accels ( as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1261870/change-gnome-evolution-keyboard-accels) thread explains ), to be able to open menu items by short-keys. No luck here either.

I'm running evolution 3.28.5-0 on ubuntu0.18.04.1

If someone could please help me I would be most grateful.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer:

Press the Alt key. This will momentarily show the menu bar. The while keeping pressing the Alt key you can choose View->Layout->Show Menu Bar

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I could not hold down the Alt key and select the View settings using the mouse. I had to hold down the Alt key and press 'V' key to access the options and then was able to set to show the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pressing the Alt key alone will only cause the menu bar to appear temporarily in certain OSes like Windows, I believe. Alt + v should work in most flavors of Linux.

Comment: Hello, what does this add compared to other answers?

Comment: It's an attempt to add clarity as to WHY simply pressing Alt will not work for many users.

Comment: That could have been easily a comment to any other answer mentioning Alt/Alt + V

Comment: Apparently I don't have sufficient reputation to comment, so I was attempting to provide something helpful in the only way I could.